# Android Give onTouchEvent priority over onClickListeners (multitouch)

Tags: android, multi-touch, touch-event

I'm working on a multitouch activity, and inside this activity I've written an  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){} that catch the multitouch events.
The problem is that when I multitouch, for example a button, the onClickLister of that button get executed instead of the onTouchEvent.
I'd like to ask if exist a way of ignoring the onClickListener of all my buttons/views when onTouchEvent is detected.

Thanks

Comment: Just return `true` in your `onTouchEvent()`

Comment: I've already tried that, but it doesn't work